# Is it possible to split questions?

Tags: discussion

The following question has been asked, but the answer is different depending on the host OS. Is it possible to split it into several questions rather than having a (very good, but) confusing answer?

[Emulate on a PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/165/emulation-on-a-pc)

Comment: How about multiple answers?

Answer (score 2):

You can post multiple questions, and they can have multiple answers. Which I guess is splitting, manually.

I would advise against this however, unless one question is so broad, its answer so unwieldy that it's hard to read and understand.

As Jivings suggests, multiple answers (or even multiple sections in one answer) can provide a reasonable solution without needing to duplicate common information.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the scope of the question so that it's about emulating the Raspi on Linux.

[Emulation on a Linux PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/165/emulation-on-a-linux-pc)

I've also created a similar question for Windows:

[Emulation on a Windows PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/344/emulation-on-a-windows-pc)

---

Slightly unrelated, but I think [this question "Emulating image for programming without a device"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/249/emulating-image-for-programming-without-a-device) should be reopened - I believe it's about compiling software (with an ARM compiler), rather than emulating (a la VM).